# ползунок слайдера, drag and drop

Tags: javascript

Сделал такой ползунок для слайдера:

```js
const sliderPoint = document.querySelector('.slider_point');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

sliderPoint.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const shiftX = e.clientX - sliderPoint.getBoundingClientRect().left;

  moveAt(e.pageX);

  function moveAt(pageX) {
    sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX(${pageX - shiftX}px)`;
  }

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    const sliderRightMax = slider.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    const sliderLeftMax = slider.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const sliderPointRightPos = sliderPoint.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    const sliderPointLeftPos = sliderPoint.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const movementOutRight = (sliderPointRightPos - event.pageX - sliderPoint.offsetWidth + shiftX) < 0 ? true : false;
    const movementOutLeft = (sliderPointLeftPos + event.pageX - sliderPoint.offsetWidth + shiftX) < 0 ? true : false;
    if (sliderPointRightPos >= sliderRightMax) {
      sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX(${sliderRightMax - sliderPoint.offsetWidth}px)`;
      if (movementOutRight) {
        // console.log('Движение в правой части на правом краю слайдера');
      } else {
        // console.log('Движение в левой части на левом краю слайдера');
        moveAt(event.pageX);
      }

      return false;
    }

    if (sliderPointLeftPos <= sliderLeftMax) {
      sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;
      if (movementOutLeft) {
        // console.log('Движение в левой части на левом краю слайдера');
      } else {
        // console.log('Движение в правой части на правом краю слайдера');
        moveAt(event.pageX);
      }

      return false;
    }
    // console.log(' ');
    moveAt(event.pageX);
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

  document.onmouseup = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.onmouseup = null;
  };


});

sliderPoint.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider_point {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">

  <div class="slider_point"></div>

</div>
```

Но если я сделаю своему контейнеру со слайдером отступ/отцентрирую как-то, то ползунок смещается на то расстояние, как смещен контейнер.

```js
const sliderPoint = document.querySelector('.slider_point');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

sliderPoint.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const shiftX = e.clientX - sliderPoint.getBoundingClientRect().left;

  moveAt(e.pageX);

  function moveAt(pageX) {
    sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX(${pageX - shiftX}px)`;
  }

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    const sliderRightMax = slider.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    const sliderLeftMax = slider.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const sliderPointRightPos = sliderPoint.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    const sliderPointLeftPos = sliderPoint.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const movementOutRight = (sliderPointRightPos - event.pageX - sliderPoint.offsetWidth + shiftX) < 0 ? true : false;
    const movementOutLeft = (sliderPointLeftPos + event.pageX - sliderPoint.offsetWidth + shiftX) < 0 ? true : false;
    if (sliderPointRightPos >= sliderRightMax) {
      sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX(${sliderRightMax - sliderPoint.offsetWidth}px)`;
      if (movementOutRight) {
        // console.log('Движение в правой части на правом краю слайдера');
      } else {
        // console.log('Движение в левой части на левом краю слайдера');
        moveAt(event.pageX);
      }

      return false;
    }

    if (sliderPointLeftPos <= sliderLeftMax) {
      sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;
      if (movementOutLeft) {
        // console.log('Движение в левой части на левом краю слайдера');
      } else {
        // console.log('Движение в правой части на правом краю слайдера');
        moveAt(event.pageX);
      }

      return false;
    }
    // console.log(' ');
    moveAt(event.pageX);
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

  document.onmouseup = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.onmouseup = null;
  };


});

sliderPoint.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider_point {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">

  <div class="slider_point"></div>

</div>
```

Подскажите как исправить, в чём проблема

Comment: Вам бы наверное подошел ползунок из моего ответа отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1207928/406363  Хоть он проблемму не решает, но он более юзабильный.

Comment: Мне кажется вы переусложнили код, для решения задачи достаточно знать 
- положение курсора
- размер слайдера
- размер ползунка
при mouseMove вычислять новое положение ползунка и ограничивать его через Math.min/Math.max

Comment: Проблема в том, что не учитывается смещение слайдера относительно его контейнера

Comment: Плюс, непонятно что хранится в переменной shiftX, что за переменные movementOutRight, movementOutLeft, а так же почему в половине случаев используется moveAt, а в половине - напрямую `sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX`?

Comment: @Grundy `shiftX` это расстояние от того места куда ты кликнул, до левого края ползунка. `movementOutRight` это я пытался поймать момент, когда достигнут правый край. И для левой части соответсвенно. Когда я обращался напрямую, я обнулял позицию, ставил ползунок влево/вправо. Вызов moveAt - это обычное движение

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, из-за размазанности логики - тяжело разобраться. В любом случае - не учитывается смещение при mousedown первом, поэтому и скачет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так решил (не спрашивайте как я это сделал, сам не понимаю)

```js
const sliderPoint = document.querySelector('.slider_point');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

sliderPoint.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const shiftX = e.clientX - sliderPoint.getBoundingClientRect().left;

  onMouseMove(e);

  function moveAt(pageX) {
    // console.log(pageX);
    const sliderLeftMax = slider.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX(${pageX - sliderLeftMax - shiftX}px)`;
  }

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    const sliderRightMax = slider.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    const sliderLeftMax = slider.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const sliderPointRightPos = sliderPoint.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    const sliderPointLeftPos = sliderPoint.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const movementOutRight = (sliderPointRightPos - event.pageX - sliderPoint.offsetWidth + shiftX) < 0 ? true : false;
    const movementOutLeft = (-sliderPointLeftPos + event.pageX - sliderPoint.offsetWidth - shiftX) < 0 ? true : false;

    if (sliderPointRightPos >= sliderRightMax) {
      sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX(${slider.offsetWidth - sliderPoint.offsetWidth}px)`;
      if (movementOutRight) {
        // console.log('Движение в правой части на правом краю слайдера');
      } else {
        // console.log('Движение в левой части на правом краю слайдера');
        moveAt(event.pageX);
      }

      return false;
    }

    if (sliderPointLeftPos <= sliderLeftMax) {
      sliderPoint.style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;
      if (movementOutLeft) {
        // console.log('Движение в левой части на левом краю слайдера');
      } else {
        // console.log('Движение в правой части на левом краю слайдера');
        moveAt(event.pageX);
      }

      return false;
    }
    // console.log(' ');
    moveAt(event.pageX);
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  removeMouseUp();

  function removeMouseUp() {
    document.onmouseup = function() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      document.onmouseup = null;
    };
  }

});

sliderPoint.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider_point {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">

  <div class="slider_point"></div>

</div>
```